how to make enemies chasing the player by using finding path algorithm in C++?
I'm doing a game using SDL2 and C++. My problem is I'm trying to use finding path algorithm (A*) to create an enemies that chases the player. My idea is to get the update of every moment and rect of the player and then create path between the player and the enemies. Here is the problem: This makes my game very lag. It's because I create path every tick. Can anyone help me the idea of this to make my game run faster?
void Engine::update()
{
    Astar::Vec2i v{int(player->GetOrigin()->X/16), int(player->GetOrigin()->Y/16)};
    Astar::Vec2i e{int(enemy1->GetOrigin()->X/16), int(enemy1->GetOrigin()->Y/16)};
    auto path = generator.findPath(v, e);
    for (auto &co : path)
    {
        std::cout << co.x << " " << co.y << std::endl;
    }
    // to get the rect of the enemies and player and then create path
}


This kind of algorithms usually require transport optimization. Unless it's an 'interceptor" algorithm where chaser can move freely and extrapolates position of "target" (e.g. a SAM missile). There can be a decart graph , or similar structure, describing legal positions and legal moves, known as a navmesh, player's position is snapped to it. Chaser uses navmesh as a reference to find how to follow target. You might look into code of opensource bots fo Counterstrike and similar. Navmeshes often are prebuild, even being a part of game reasources, unless it's a modifiable in run-time environment

thank you for your support. I'll find out to apply

If the lag only occurs when this algorithm is active, it should be the cause of the lag (make sure this is the case before doing any optimizations).
Since the algorithm is too slow to run every tick, the following optimizations might help:

Divide the enemies into X groups of equal size. Update only one group per tick. (e.g. 3 groups, so on the 1st tick, only calculate enemies in the 1st group, on the next tick in the 2nd group,... on the 4th tick update the 1st group again).
Update the A* algorithm only if the enemy has moved at least distance D on the previous path. (Maybe this distance depends on the remaining distance to the player, e.g. `D = std::min(playerDist*0.2, D_MAX))
Instead of a full update every cycle, just add the player movement to the previous calculation and do a full update only every X ticks.
Check your findPath function to see if it can be optimized (e.g. use precalculations from previous run, define waypoints to accelerate the A* algorithm)

There are more options... (e.g. multithreading and background tasks, ...)

thank you so much for your help. I'll try your suggestions

You may also only choose some of them. This depends on your game/code.

Can you suggest any other options of finding path in my case?

This depends on your current data model. Algorithm run time depdends on the amount of input data (in most cases), so if you could reduce the input data of the algorithm, it should run faster.  Maybe you can identify what does take so long in the calculation and try to optimize this (precalculation, cache optimization, ...).

First, I think it's not necessary to call findPath every frame for a normal enemy AI.You can do it with an appropriate rate.
A* algorithm is designed for static environments but obviously your player will keep moving, that means every result for findPath call only useful to current frame, this is a huge waste.
You can check the D*(Dynamic A Star) algorithm, it's designed for dynamic environments, is more suitable to your need. But it is still very expensive to perform.
If your enemey AI do not need a very accurate path, you can replace A* findPath with some more simple algorithm. Such as this.
And you can check Navimesh, it is a popular solution in modern game. Its main idea is divide your game map into a series area. The algorithm like A* find a way of areas, the simple algorithm like I said above will lead the agent to target point in a area.
The pathfinding is a complex topic, here just my view point. My English is not very good, please forgive me if there are any mistakes. Hope it can help you.

I'm clear. Thank for your helpp
